# How to form a list of dictionaries from a list nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

How to form a list of dictionaries from a list nested dictionary ?

**Input**

`ip = {'Science' : [88, 89], 'Arts' : [77, 78] }`

**Expected Output**

`op = [{'Science' : 88, 'Arts' : 77}, {'Science' : 89, 'Arts' : 78}]`

**Tried the below :**

```
op = []
for i, j in zip(ip.keys(), ip.values()):
   op.append({i:j[0]})
   op.append({i:j[1]})
print(op)
```

**My Result:**

`[{'Science': 88}, {'Science': 89}, {'Arts': 77}, {'Arts': 78}]`

Comment: I suppose you are trying to convert columner to row wise, just want to ask is the length of the value list is same for all keys?

Answer (score 2):

Zip the lists to get corresponding values, zip them with the keys to build dicts.

```
op = [dict(zip(ip, vs))
      for vs in zip(*ip.values())]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try list comprehension

```py
[{k:ip[k][i] for k in ip.keys()} for i in range(len(list(ip.values())[0]))]
```

```
[{'Science': 88, 'Arts': 77}, {'Science': 89, 'Arts': 78}]
```

Comment: Just don't name any variable `input` since it's a built in function and sooner or later will cause hard to discover bugs

Comment: that is correct, just wanted to keep the same name as op

Comment: Didn't mean to be picky. I think it's worth to mention stuff if you notice (even if it's not directly connected with a question) , sometimes it's so out of scope one can only signal the problem is there (and maybe share a link to some resource) sometimes it's minor and can be improved at once. Cheers!